# Need Advice: VBA using Excel sheets in such a way as they don't lock

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2016

I could use some advice. I'm trying to find the best way to handle the following situation.

I have an Access Database that accesses an Excel File through VBA in a shared location.
When one user is running the code it locks up that file and if they exit in the middle of the process or get an error the file locks and they have to end task before any other users can access that file for their own attempt at the same type of process.

I'm trying to think of a way to stop this situation from happening.

One thing I was thinking of was to create a second file in case the original file was in use but that doesn't really solve the issue because the file is still "Locked" till the other user ends task on it. (Reminder this only happens if there is an error and the database closes otherwise everything is smooth).

Another Idea I had was to force Excel to close whenever the database is closed but this could cause issues because they may have other excel sheets open and if they aren't saved then they could lose critical data.

I tried to make it so the file was read only when accessed
`Set UploadFile = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\page\data\NFInventory\Apps\CID\UPLOADS\(HH) RC Uploads\CIDCATALOG_HHU_INSN.xls", True, ReadOnly = True)` 
But that doesn't work.

Any thoughts or Idea's would be greatly appreciated!

Code Snip (Files that are my problem are the CIDCATALOG_HH files):

```
'Open Workbook and continue processing
Set UploadFile = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\page\data\NFInventory\Apps\CID\UPLOADS\(HH) RC Uploads\CIDCATALOG_HHU_INSN.xls", True, ReadOnly = True)

With UploadFile.Worksheets("CIDCATALOG_HHU")
    .Range("A4").Value = "UPDPART    " & [Forms]![InSSubCanButton]![InSeasonFinalReview].[Form]![year].Value & ""
End With

'Delete Duplicates
    'lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'With myWorkbook.Worksheets("InSMasterQuery")
    '.Cells(1, 10).Offset(1, 0).Resize(lr - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCAT(RC[-10],RC[-21])
    '.Range("A1:I" & lrow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=10, Header:=xlYes
    'End With
    
With myWorkbook.Worksheets("InSMasterQuery")
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A:A").Value = .Range("A:A").Value
        .Range("A:CU").WrapText = False

    'Packs
    .Range("A2:A" & lrow).Copy
    UploadFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHU").Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    UploadFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHU").Range("A:A").Value = UploadFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHU").Range("A:A").Value
    
    'Retail
    .Range("D2:D" & lrow).Copy
    UploadFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHU").Range("B5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    'Orig Retail
    .Range("E2:E" & lrow).Copy
    UploadFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHU").Range("V5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'DRC
    .Range("F2:F" & lrow).Copy
    UploadFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHU").Range("W5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    'Offer
    .Range("C2:C" & lrow).Copy
    UploadFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHU").Range("I5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    myWorkbook.Worksheets("InSMasterQuery").Activate
    myWorkbook.Save
End With
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Upload File Formatting set EB RL Retails
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Set ws = UploadFile.Worksheets("CIDCATALOG_HHU")
    UploadFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHU").Activate

With UploadFile.Worksheets("CIDCATALOG_HHU")
    lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Retail Setup
    For i = 5 To lrow
     If ws.Range("W" & i) = "OR" Then
            ws.Range("C" & i) = "88888.88"
      End If
    Next i
End With
    
UploadFile.Close savechanges:=True
Set UploadFile = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\page\data\NFInventory\Apps\CID\UPLOADS\(HH) RC Uploads\CIDCATALOG_HHU_INSN.xls", True, ReadOnly = True)

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Export to In Season Tracking Table CID db Backend
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO InS_tbl_original([Pack_Number], [Description], [New Retail], [Original Retail], [DRC], [Brand Offer], [Season], [Markdown End Date], [Requested], [Request_Completed_Date], [Notes], [Merch Code], [Merchandiser]) " _
                                & "SELECT [Pack_Number], [Description], [Req_Low_Retail], [High Retail], [In Season DRC], [Brand Offer], [Season_id], [Markdown_End_Date], '" & Request & "', NOW(), [Notes], [MerchCode], [Merchandiser] " _
                                & "FROM InSMasterQuery"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "InsMasterQuery", acSaveNo

'Clear Temp Tables
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tblInSeasonTemp"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Open and Export to Copy File
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Export Retail and Copy file to Desktop in Excel file
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryCopyFiletbl", acFormatXLSX, "C:\Users\" & Owner & "\Desktop\ " & Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YY") & " " & strSeason & " In Season CopyFile.xlsx", False
    
    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set myWorkbook2 = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & Owner & "\Desktop\ " & Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YY") & " " & strSeason & " In Season CopyFile.xlsx")
    appExcel.Visible = False

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Check if CopyFile file is already in use
CopyF = IsWorkBookOpen("\\page\data\NFInventory\Apps\CID\UPLOADS\(HH) RC Uploads\CIDCATALOG_HHC.xls")
Do Until CopyF = False
CopyF = IsWorkBookOpen("\\page\data\NFInventory\Apps\CID\UPLOADS\(HH) RC Uploads\CIDCATALOG_HHC.xls")
    If CopyF = True Then
        nConfirmation = MsgBox("File is currently in use, Try again?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "File Locked")
        If nConfirmation = vbYes Then
          Else
            myWorkbook2.Close
            Set myWorkbook2 = Nothing
            appExcel.Quit
            Set appExcel = Nothing
          Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
    End If
Loop

'Define Copy File
Set CopyFile = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\page\data\NFInventory\Apps\CID\UPLOADS\(HH) RC Uploads\CIDCATALOG_HHC.xls", True, ReadOnly = True)

With myWorkbook2.Worksheets("qryCopyFiletbl")
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Packs-Pages
    lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2:F" & lrow).Copy
    CopyFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHC").Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    CopyFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHC").Range("A:A").Value = CopyFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHC").Range("A:A").Value
    CopyFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHC").Range("B:B").Value = CopyFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHC").Range("B:B").Value
    CopyFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHC").Range("D:D").Value = CopyFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHC").Range("D:D").Value
    CopyFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHC").Range("F:F").Value = CopyFile.Sheets("CIDCATALOG_HHC").Range("F:F").Value
    myWorkbook2.Worksheets("qryCopyFiletbl").Activate
    myWorkbook2.Save
End With

CopyFile.Close savechanges:=True
Set CopyFile = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\page\data\NFInventory\Apps\CID\UPLOADS\(HH) RC Uploads\CIDCATALOG_HHC.xls", True, ReadOnly = True)
```

Comment: For a similar situation I use an Excel file that on close saves itself as hidden, read-only "mirror" file that can be queried without interruption for regular file use. That way I can just open a file that is already read-only and not worry about crashes.

Comment: In my situation the code edits the file adds data and saves it as something else on their own desktop. If I set the file to read only within the file properties it gives the save as pop up. How do you get around that?

Comment: `ReadOnly = True` not `ReadOnly := True` ?  Might be useful to show more of your code, including the "SaveAs" part.

Comment: The code is HUGE. But I will add some snips of what you requested.

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` at the top of your module?  If not, what happens when you add it?

Comment: ...in a module without `Option Explicit` and where `ReadOnly` is not declared `ReadOnly = True` evaluates to `False`.  If you want to pass `True` to the `ReadOnly` parameter when opening a file you need `ReadOnly:=True`

Comment: @TimWilliams oh good call! I was not using option explicit but I have added that in. It runs with that added now (I had to define a few things I was previously defining) and it will run. If I update the readonly part to how you suggest I get the save as popup which I'm trying to avoid. I specifically tell it how and where to save but doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Can you pare down your code to a few lines which replicate the problem - open the file make a change then close it: just enough to trigger the dialog which you don't want?  There's so much going on in what you posted it's difficult to tease anything out of it.

Comment: @TimWilliams yeah I was worried that was the case. I mean the main thing are the open lines `Set UploadFile = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\page\data\NFInventory\Apps\CID\UPLOADS\(HH) RC Uploads\CIDCATALOG_HHU_INSN.xls", True)` so  if someone has the file locked they can't open the file when this line comes up. The other issue is if, after this line (and the file isn't locked) but the close for any reason it keeps the file open and locked in their name. I need it so the file is always accessible and editable

Comment: Does whoever manages to open the file need to edit it and save it (in the same path) with the changes, or is it intended as a "read only" file?  You say "the code edits the file adds data and saves it as something else on their own desktop" but I don't see that step in your posted code.

Comment: @TimWilliams in the snip that posted it shows the copy paste that is happening to the file. The process works like this (Opens file -> copy and pastes data to it -> saves it as something else locally -> closes original and new file) the problem I have is anywhere in the middle of that process the file is locked and other users can't access it. I think the only way to make this work is to just copy the file locally to the users machine and use that.

Comment: Yes sounds like copy first then open the local copy is the way to go.